# Requiring password after returning from blank screen not working Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: login, password, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (updated from Ubuntu 14.04, which maby was updated from previous version, I'm not sure).
When I try to lock the screen, it gets blank an after I move the mouse the desktop shows up without asking for password. This started while I was on 14.04.
In "System Settings" > "Brightness & Lock" I have:
  Lock: on
  Lock screen after: Screen turns off
  Require my password when waking from suspend: **checked**
In "System Settings" > "Security & Privacy" > tab "Security" I have:
  Require my password when:
    Waking from suspend: checked
    Returning from blank screen: **checked**
      if screen has been blank for: **0 seconds (lock immediately)**

I tried to lock the screen from the main menu > "Lock/Switch Account..." and using Ctrl+Alt+L. Both make the screen blank and after that if I move the mouse the desktop just shows (the blank screen just disapears) without asking for password. It's like locking is not working.
If I leave the computer, the display dims and after that if I move the mouse - the desktop shows without asking for password. All that worked a year ago (or something like that).

Something interesting. I made a new user. When I login with it and press Ctrl+Alt+L or use "Lock/Switch Account..." **it works** - the standart ubuntu login screen shows up.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced a similar issue. The only action I found to permanently resolve the matter was to reinstall 16.04 from a boot-able USB.

Step by step directions for this process can be found here: 
 [Reinstall Ubuntu with USB](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-window7s)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this will be the last resort.
I'm searching for specific fix.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 17, you need to install the "Brightness and lock" app. To find it, go to your"show applications", search for "lock", and it should pop up for your to install.

Comment: My version is 16.04. This solution might help, but I've already reinstalled and the problem is gone. Maybe this can help someone else with the same issue. Thank you!